# Creating Azure Self Signed Certificate

Tags: azure, certificate, self-signed

We have an on premise web site which needs to communicate with windows azure service and sql azure service.

I need to create a self signed certificate but makecer.exe is not available on web service. Could someone please confirm whether I **must create** the self signed on specific on premise web server or I can create on **any machine and install on web server**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the self signed certificate on **any** machine and install it on **any other**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free Self Signed Certificate Generator (http://www.itiverba.com/en/software/itisscg.php) to create self-signed certificates. 

If you create the certificate on another comuter than your server, just export the certificate in a PFX file **including the private Key** and then copy the PFX on your server and install the certificate AND its private key.

If you use a Linux server, the tool allows you to export the certificate in PEM files.